# Shaft which can independently rotate and translate axially

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motion

I would like to mount a sensor onto a shaft which can be translated axially as well rotated independently. This arrangement permits me to capture a 360 deg scan and then translate the shaft axially to scan at a different height.

How should one use a lead-screw and stepper motor coupled with some other mechanism to achieve this (non-helical) motion ? Thanks for any tip.

Comment: Maybe it sounds dumb, but how about just rotate the shaft and translating the sensor ?

Comment: Have a look at cnc machines - they know exactly where the tool and object is...

Comment: Although it is possible to do as you suggest, I will be negating the advantage of the long lead-screw which I possess. Would need yet another means of translating the sensor axially.